# UpdateError: Receiving Error ORA - 01427 Single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, ora-01427

I am trying to update a column based on another column in the same table (student table) and a column
from another table (school table)

Code is:

```
update student_table
set student_code =
(select l.student_code
from school_table l, student_table n
where l.school = n.schoolname)
```

I get the following error

ORA - 01427 Single-row subquery returns more than one row

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be helpful to have a plain English explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.  Having said that, it appears to me that you can accomplish what you want to do with the following SQL [assuming one to many relationship between school_table and student_table] having the inner select as a corelated sub-query with the outer update statement:

```
update student_table 
set student_code = (select l.student_code 
                    from school_table 
                    where school_table.school = student_table.schoolname) 
;
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Roger

Answer (score 5):

If you run your subquery you'll find it returning more than one row. You are trying to update a column to be equal to the result of your subquery so it expects only one value. You should limit your subquery to only return one row such as using max() or min() or, perhaps you meant to join to the outer student_table? Try:

```
update student_table n
set student_code =
(select l.student_code
from school_table l
where l.school = n.schoolname);
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying.  Since my inner query is returning more than one value it is giving me that error.  The inner select statement gives me the correct values I want to update. I tried a merge statement, but it was giving me a different error. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

We all know exactly what the error says. SET only expects one value per column to be set. What we want to achieve is Update all rows for a given column using values from another table's column.

Now here's the solution:

```
BEGIN
For i in (select col_X, col_Y from table1) 
LOOP
Update table2 set col1 = i.col_X where col2 = i.col_Y;
END LOOP;
END;
```

That's how exactly you run it on SQLDeveloper worksheet. They say it's slow but that's the only solution that worked for me on this case.

Answer (score 0):

your inner query..

```
select l.student_code
from school_table l, student_table n
where l.school = n.schoolname
```

might return more than one value. Run the inner query and check the number of the value.

Comment: Yes, the inner select gives me more than one value.  I was trying to update them all at once.  The select I was running is giving me the correct values I want to update, but the update statement is where I am running into trouble.  Thanks Again!

Comment: @user1307149:I understand you are trying to update all rows at once,but the inner query is returning more than one rows ,Imagine `set student_code = <multiple student_code>` how can you assign multiple value to a student_code,obviously it will give you error .Think like that which student_code in update will update with the inner query student_code.Try to find the relation between the two.

Answer (score 0):

restrict the output of the inner query to one value to successfully run your query.

```
select l.student_code
from school_table l, student_table n
where l.school = n.schoolname
```

[check this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01427.php)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add and rownum=1 to your subquery conditions if you DO NOT care about the value from the list or DO sure that they are the same.